# Query Kubernetes cluster for capacity to reach CPU `limit`

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes allows to separately specify `limit` and `request` CPU allocations for containers. The `request` allocation is guaranteed, but to what extent the `limit` allocation can be used is subject to availability. That availability in turn depends on several properties:

1. how many CPU cores on the node are assigned to containers in the `guaranteed` QoS class, since those are not available to the scheduler for other containers.
2. the (fractional) number of CPU cores that are not assigned to *any* container
3. the (fractional) number of CPU cores that are assigned to a container not in the `guaranteed` QoS class and currently (partially) idle.
4. The `limit`s of other non-`guaranteed` containers on the same pod.

Is there a way to quantize that availability, i.e. how close a given Kubernetes container could currently come to fully utilizing its CPU `limit` if it could cause enough CPU load?